# Insert ROW_NUMBER() into column starting from offset

Tags: sql, insert, offset, row-number

I'm stuck with a simple problem.
I would like to add an offset when insert inside into a column the ROW_NUMBER(), but how to make it work?
For example:

```
DECLARE @LastPosition int = 5;
```

and then

```
Insert INTO @Table
SELECT myt.Id, @LastPosition + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)
FROM mytable myt
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have should work just fine.

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/894ae/1)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it works, it was the @LastPosition query that failed; I get a workaround with ISNULL(a,b). Thanks to everyone and very interesting SQL Fiddle!
Thank you very much